# How can I solve the multiple dots issue and overwrite the original file

Tags: ffmpeg, bash-scripting

First question.

When converting, I want to get a file in the format **artist name - song title.mp3**. The problem is that if there are several dots in the title, I will get the **artist name.mp3**. I use this code found on the Internet.

```bsh
    for FILE in *.{ogg,waw} ; do
    ffmpeg -i "$FILE" "${FILE%.*}.mp3"
    echo "Done!"
```

How do I edit to fix the dots issue?

Second question.

If I want to trim the file later, how do I tell ffmpeg to overwrite the original file? For this I want to use this code.

```bsh
    echo -n "Specify the file "
    read line
    echo -n "Start of file "
    read number
    echo -n "End of file "
    read number2
    ffmpeg -i $line -ss $number -to $number2 -c copy $line
    echo "Done!"
```

Feel free to suggest more elegant solutions. Thanks.

Comment: Your first example looks okay – are you sure you're not accidentally using `%%.*` instead of the correct `%.*`?

Comment: There really was an error, and I posted the update code without an error. My carelessness ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I edit to fix the dots issue?

It looks OK, but you're missing `done`:

```
for FILE in *.{ogg,waw} ; do
ffmpeg -i "$FILE" "${FILE%.*}.mp3"
echo "Done!"
done
```

> how do I tell ffmpeg to overwrite the original file?

You can't. `ffmpeg` is not able to perform in-place editing. Output to a different directory or provide a different output file name and then delete the original.

Comment: Thanks for correction!